# Styles loading issue when clicking back button in my jQuery Mobile project

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, loading

I am working on a project that used jQuery Mobile. I have used a carousel: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html

```
$.mobile.changePage("#home",{ transition: "slide"} );
```

is used to navigate to the home page, and

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#home", function() {

    var url = 'http://www.example.com/new-products';

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        //data: "login=" + login + "&password=" + pass,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var products = data;


            var content = "";
            $("#owl-example").html(content)
            $.each(products, function(index, product) {


            // Custom Navigation Events
            $(".next").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.next');
            })
            $(".prev").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.prev');
            })
            $(".play").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.play', 1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as second parameter
            })
            $(".stop").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.stop');
            })
  content += "<div class='products'><div class='img-container'><img width='100' height='100' src=http://www.example.com" + product.image + "></div>" + product.name + "<br><span>" + product.points + "</span></div>";
            });
            $("#owl-example").html(content);

            $.mobile.loading('hide');


            callCaserole();

            // Custom Navigation Events
            $(".next").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.next');
            })
            $(".prev").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.prev');
            })
            $(".play").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.play', 1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as second parameter
            })
            $(".stop").click(function() {
                owl.trigger('owl.stop');
            })



        },
        error: function(httpReq, status, exception) {
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
            alert(status + " " + exception);
        }
    })
}
```

is used to load carousel. First time it is loading fine. But if we click the browser's back button to come to the page, it won't load styles. How to solve this issue?

This is a single page app and page changes are done using div `id`s

```
<div id="home" data-role="page"></div>
<div id="secondPage" data-role="page"></div>
<div id="firstPage" data-role="page"></div>
```

Comment: had the same issue when developing single page apps. What I did was to have the forms, sections with input fields and slideshows in separate pages. This usually solved the issue.

Comment: does the content of the carousel change each time you go back to the page, or is it the same. If the same, you don't need to run the code on every page show because it is already in the dom. Just use pagecreate instead.

Comment: @ezanker it needs to refresh every time go back to the page, because this is for crosplatform  mobile app. Otherwise we don't have any refresh event.